Flatness and pushforward
Suppose $\mathcal{P}$ a coherent sheaf over $X\times Y$, flat over both the factors. Here $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective surfaces over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. We know that $\operatorname{ch}\mathcal{P}_x=(0,a,b)$ and $\operatorname{ch}\mathcal{P}_y=(0,a',b')$ for $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. Can we say anything about $\operatorname{ch}(\pi_{Y*}\mathcal{P})$?
Here $\mathcal{P}_x=\mathcal{P}|_{\{x\}\times Y}=i_x^*(\mathcal{P}),$ where $i_x:\{x\}\times Y\to X\times Y$ is the embedding.

Consider, for example, the structure sheaf of the diagonal on $X \times X$.

Yeah, just realized that, and that's why removed the rank question.

By Grothendieck--Riemann--Roch, if you know the Chern character of a sheaf, you can find the Chern character of its pushforward. However, if you only know the restrictions of the Chern character to the fibers, you miss some information, so you cannot find exactly what you want. However, some pieces you can. For instance, the rank of the pushforward can be found.

Dear @Sasha, can you help me figure out how I can find the rank of the pushforward with this info? Thanks.

I wrote the computation as an answer.

One has
$$
\mathrm{rank}(\pi_{Y*}\mathcal{P}) =
\mathrm{rank}((\pi_{Y,y})_*\mathcal{P}_y) =
\chi(\mathcal{P}_y) =
\deg(\mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{P}_y) \cdot \mathrm{td}_X),
$$
where $y$ is a general point on the base, $\pi_{Y,y}$ is the restriction of $\pi_Y$ to the fiber over $y$, and the pushforwards are considered in the derived sense.

Dear @Sasha, thank you so much for your answer. This is very helpful. Can you kindly tell me how you got the first two first two equalities?
So, we get that the rank is equal to $\chi(\mathcal{P}_y)$, hence we can think of $\mathcal{P}_y$ as a sheaf on the fiber over $y$, which is isomorphic to $X$? Then Riemann-Roch for surfaces gives us, $\chi(\mathcal{P}_y)=0\cdot \chi(\mathcal{O}_X)-(K_X\cdot a)/2+b=-(K_X\cdot a)/2+b$, where $ch(\mathcal{P}_y)=(0,a,b)$.

The first equality is true because the rank is equal to the rank at the general point. The second equality means that the rank of an object of the derived category is the alternatig sum of the ranks of its cohomology, i.e., the Euler characteristic.
